# Complex Number Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

[This is that eqn , I asked many people but nobody could solve , hope this community could help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgfJx.png)

Comment: Use $\cos z=\dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that \begin{eqnarray*}
\cos(z) &=& \frac{1}{2} (e^{iz} + e^{-iz} ) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}(e^{i^2 \ln(2- \sqrt{3})} + e^{-i^2\ln(2-\sqrt{3})}). \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}(e^{\ln\left(\frac{1}{(2-\sqrt{3})}\right)} + e^{\ln(2 - \sqrt{3})}) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{2 - \sqrt{3}} + 2-\sqrt{3}\right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \left( 4\right) =2.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Yes I think that Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since $z=e^{i\theta}$ (Euler's representation)
One can simply write $$cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$

Now calculate fther to get the ans?

Hint: $e^{ln(a)}=a$. That's all you need to know.